# 301 htaccess redirection from old links to new links

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink, redirect

Recently I have rebuilt my website

and I would like mainly to redirect old link structure like:

```
site.com/view.php?page=66
```

To New link structure:

```
site.com/page/66
```

with the same id so I can do a rule in htaccess that redirect old links to new one and I can do the rest with the same structure such as:

```
site.com/category.php?id=1
```

To

```
site.com/cat/1
```

I don't want to lose the rank in google and my site links in search engines !

any advises or recommendation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code in /htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /view\.php\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [NC,L,R=301]
```

it redirects "view.php?page=12345" to "/page/12345".

Comment: Thanks a lot .. it works fine now ,, thanks for your concern